# Python :Iterating list of list

Tags: python, list, data-structures, tree

```
['P', ['Q', ['R', ['S', 'T'], ['U', 'V']]]]
```

This is my list and I need to iterate over it in a specific manner. The output for the following should be :-

```
P -> Q 
Q -> R
R -> S U
S -> T
U -> V
```

I tried following thing:-

```
def traverse_mystructure(tree):
    queue = [tree]

    for list in tree:
        print list
        traverse_mystructure(list);
```

I am not able to get this kind of output with the above.Is it possible to obtain this kind of output ?

Comment: Why do you need a `queue`, that's normally use for an iterative solution vs. recursive. BTW: don't use `list` as a variable name - it hides the python `list` type. Breadth first print will be simpler iteratively (queue).

Comment: You also need to handle the base case when doing recursion. The base case here is when tree is an empty list

Comment: I assume, your class mate asked the same question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40791675/using-nltk-tree?noredirect=1#comment68807105_40791675) today.

Comment: @schwobaseggl don't know about it..

Answer (score 1):

I have done this roughly by assuming only the given pattern in your question.

```
inputList = ['P', ['Q', ['R', ['S', 'T'], ['U', 'V']]]]

print inputList

def printSomeMore(newList):
    output = ""
    for sublist in newList:
        if (len(sublist) == 1):
            output = sublist + " ->"
        else:
            output = output + " " + sublist[0]
    return output

def printMyList(myList):
    for each in myList:
        if str(myList[0]) == str(each):
            if (len(myList) == 2):
                print each, "->", myList[-1][0]
            if (len(myList) > 2):
                value = printSomeMore(myList)
                print value
        if str(type(each)) == "<type 'list'>":
            printMyList(each)

printMyList(inputList)
```

The output that I get from this.

```
['P', ['Q', ['R', ['S', 'T'], ['U', 'V']]]]
P -> Q
Q -> R
R -> S U
S -> T
U -> V
```